# Comma separated words into new lines

Tags: text-processing

I have an input file looks like this

```
N1518    AMP,AUG,AZM,CHL 
N1520    AZM,NAL
N1524    AMP,NAL,STR
......
```

I'm trying to convert it to

```
N1518    AMP
N1518    AUG
N1518    AZM
N1518    CHL
N1520    AZM
N1520    NAL
N1524    AMP
N1524    NAL
N1524    STR
....
```

Is there an one liner to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk with multiple separators, and then iterate over fields to print the columns.

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s %s\n",$1,$i;}}' file
```

Explanation:

`-F'[ ,]+'`  : This tells awk to use both space and comma as the field separator. It also tells it to consider consecutive separators as a single separator.

`for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)` : loops over all columns starting from the second one, because we have to print the first column repeatedly.

`printf "%s %s\n",$1,$i;` : prints a line with the first column and the ith column

Comment: Works. Just replaced the space with tab since it is tab separated file. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk -F '[\t,]' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1"\t"$i}' file
N1518 AMP
N1518 AUG
N1518 AZM
N1518 CHL
N1520 AZM
N1524 AMP
N1524 NAL
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly.  It is tab separated so I replaced the space with a tab ` '[\t ,]'`

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below script and it worked fine too

count_line=`awk '{print NR}' filename| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

```
for ((i=1;i<=$count_line;i++)); do fi=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $1}' filename`; h=`awk -v i="$i"  'NR==i{print $2}' filename|awk -F "," '{print NF}'|  sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`; for ((j=1;j<=$h;j++)); do echo $fi;awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'NR==i{print $2}' filename| awk -v j="$j" -F ","  '{print $j}' ; done; done|sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
N1518 AMP
N1518 AUG
N1518 AZM
N1518 CHL
N1520 AZM
N1520 NAL
N1524 AMP
N1524 NAL
N1524 STR
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` in extended regex mode `-E` option, your problem is doable as:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/^((\S+\t)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/;P;D' inp
```

**Output:**

```
N1518   AMP
N1518   AUG
N1518   AZM
N1518   CHL
N1520   AZM
N1520   NAL
N1524   AMP
N1524   NAL
N1524   STR
```